# Running Neo4j 3.0 with specific database folder

Tags: neo4j

In Neo4j 2.x we could easily start a server using specified data folder with simple command:

```
./neo4j console -path data/databases/my_graph.db/
```

In 3.0 it seams to ignore the path setting
Also - when using neo4j-shell in both 2.x and 3.0 it correctly accepts -path argument and changes data being used.

How can I start neo4j using specified data folder?

Why would they change it in such incompatible way?

EDIT 1:
I've found a comment on this [changelog](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j-3.0-changelog#300-m05)

Still they do not specify how to overwrite config when starting neo4j.

Answer (score 1):

The DBMS path is now stored in **/etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf**
The value it is stored as is **dbms.directories.data**

Faced with the same problem, and not able to figure out how to start with -path,
what i did instead is to **copy** the **neo4j.conf** file to a new file **neo4j.conf.bak**

Then change the dbms.directories.data value in the first file and restart the database.

Rename and swap the files to switch databases.

This might not be an ideal solution, but it works.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Well I know I could do this, but my case is to have several databases with same dataset but with different amount of items, so I would like to change them at startup moment. mayby I will go with some script that will inject dbname into neo4j.conf.template, copy it to neo4j.conf and start neo4j normally.

Comment: I have more databases as well, and want to load the one I want in py2neo in virtualenv. I changed dbms.directories.data but with no success: database results always empty, cannot load folder. Folder is owned by neo4j user.

Comment: What I've finished up doing is having default config pointing to "graph.db", but I'm using symbolic links - this way I can easily change what DB to load with some simple magic bash script.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `NEO4J_CONF` environment variable

`NEO4J_CONF=/path/to/config_dir`

You can create multiple configs and set this variable appropriately before running neo4j start

`NEO4J_CONF=/path/to/config_dir neo4j start`

So add a `neo4j.test` config directory and `neo4j.production` config directory, within them set the `dbms.active_database` property in the `neo4j.conf` file, then set the environment variable appropriately when wanting to use production/test/development.

Comment: A I have mentioned in a comment below - I ended up using symbolic links to default graph.db set in config - this too enables to easily switch from one dataset to another.

Comment: Thanks for responding,
You should select an official correct answer for your question.

Using `NEO4J_CONF` is slightly more in tune with their way of configuration, and is the most flexible solution. (Remember, you don't have to keep your configurations in /etc ...)

Comment: Here is their official knowledge base page on configuration
https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/how-do-i-quickly-switch-between-multiple-graphs-without-modifying-neo4j-conf/